# How to post data in JSON format from table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table as follows:

```html
<html>
  <head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){
   // I'd like a suggestion here
  });
});
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr><th>Name</th><th>Email</th></tr>
      <tr><td>abc</td><td>abc@gmail.com</td></tr>
      <tr><td>xyz</td><tr><td>xyz@gmail.com</td>
    </table>
    <button>click here</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want after clicking that button it should create a json object conataining all data in table send it to the another url using jquery.

Comment: what data you need to send?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select table rows with data and then use `$.fn.map` method to extract necessary values and put them in array:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
    
    var data = $('table tr:gt(0)').map(function() {
        return {
            name:  $(this.cells[0]).text(),
            email: $(this.cells[1]).text()
        };
    }).get();
    
    alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4))
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>xyz</td>
        <td>xyz@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>    
</table>
<button>click here</button>
```